# How to assign values for multiple class property like a list of items using for loop?

Tags: c#

I wish to set a list of properties at the same time, is it possible?
Thanks!

```
public class Helper
{
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }

    public void SetToFalse(List<Property> ABC)
    {
        // try to set A, B, C to false in a for loop
        foreach (var item in ABC)
        {
            item = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Why I want to do this: I wish to have a clean way to toggle the boolean properties all at once, while i cannot group the properties into a list because the context is a ViewModel and the properties are bound to the Xaml.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: What is the code for the class Property?  AFAIK you can't assign false to a class (`Property`).

Comment: What is the criteria to search properties? I mean, "all bool properties", or "ann properties, which name starts with '_'", etc.

Comment: This could be done by reflection, but I don't think this is what you want!

Comment: Parallel.ForEach(ABC,(x)=>{x=false;});

Comment: @cansik I know.. but would like to avoid it if possible as it'll be pretty slow

Comment: @Dennis An arbitrarily list; they are not restricted to any naming rules

Comment: `whitshadow`, if you want to assign dinamic amount of properties in your class with some value you cannot avoid of using the reflection. But I would realy recommend to use object initialization and just forget about your `silly idea`. But if you want to do it anyway look at my answer, it shows how to do it using reflection.

Comment: @whtshadow: well, In this case I can't see any difference with assigning values one-by-one. What do you want to achieve with this approach?

Comment: @Maris I know how to implement so in reflection beforehand; just trying to see whether SO ppl have better idea. I don't think this is "Silly" if you need to manage a couple of groups of toggle buttons which each of them are backed by a boolean property while you need to set all of them to false pretty often (it is the buttons provided by WPF Fluent Ribbon API so there is no way but setting the booleans one by one).

Comment: @Dennis because they are inside a ViewModel; I need to manage 3 groups of boolean properties within the same class (each of them have 5-8 items). Why I am asking here is that I wish to find a better way (if any) other then setting them one by one, or using the slower reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a list of rambda.

```
public class Helper
    {
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }

    public List<Action<bool>> Setters { get; set; }
    public Helper()
        {
        this.Setters = new List<Action<bool>>() 
            { b => this.A = b, b => this.B = b, b => this.C = b };
        }

    public void SetToFalse(IEnumerable<Action<bool>> setters)
        {
        // try to set A, B, C to false in a for loop
        foreach (var a in setters)
            {
            a(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Do you like this?

Comment: I didnt get what advantage you get with this way. The same way as using the object initialization by hands.

Comment: I guess he needs to do this frequently and to apply filtering etc.

Comment: @terasato yes quite frequently on several groups of boolean properties within the same class..

Answer (score 0):

This one should work.

```
Helper helper = new Helper();
//This will get all Boolean properties of your class
var properties = helper.GetType().GetProperties().Where(e=>e.PropertyType==typeof(Boolean));
//Completing all Boolean properties with "false"
foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
{
    propertyInfo.SetValue(helper,false);
}
```

**Notice - using the reflection in the runtime is a bad move(performance will go down)**

Comment: You could compile the result with a `LambdaExpression` though. https://gist.github.com/Alxandr/6052416 One could also fairly easily create a version that sets all settable properties to their default-value (ie. reset), though I think I'd rather do that by creating a `IResettable` interface (or something like that) and have the class itself implement a `Reset` method.

Comment: @Alxandr I'll try out Linq.Expression as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support that much boolean flags, I would change it to a Dictionary and do something like this:

```
class Class1
{
    private Dictionary<String, Boolean> boolenVars = new Dictionary<String, Boolean>();

    public Boolean getFlag(String key)
    {
        if (this.boolenVars.ContainsKey(key))
            return this.boolenVars[key];
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void setFlag(String key, Boolean value)
    {
        if (this.boolenVars.ContainsKey(key))
            this.boolenVars[key] = value;
        else
            this.boolenVars.Add(key, value);
    }

    public void clearFlags()
    {
        this.boolenVars.Clear();
    }
}
```

Instead of using a String-based key, you could create a enum for that purpose, to ensure there are no typos when using the flags.

This solution would not require any further code changes, even if you decide to add 7526 new Boolean Flags.

This solution also provides - if you expose the dictionary using a public getter or method - a list of all "set" boolean flags.

Answer (score -1):

You can use object initializers to do this. VS will give you intellisense for the properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx

Example:

```
class Helper
{
    public bool A { get;set;}
    public bool B { get;set;}
}

Helper myclass = new Helper { A = false, B = false };
```

This is not using a for loop but it is cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Not what op ask about.